# Drop digits after point of double variable(Java)

Tags: java, double

I have a double value, for example:

```
double a = 12.1212123456543234;
```

I need to check the number of the digits after point and drop all digits from sixteenth. Here is my code to get digits after point:

```
String [] splitter  = String.valueOf(a).split("\\.");
```

But even if the number of the digits after the point is bigger then 15, I always get 15 digits, and last digit (fifteenth) replaced by the wrong. please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Double is a 64-bit floating point number. And its precision is limited to 15-16 digits after the point, that's why you get incorrect results.

If want to work with that large numbers you probably need [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

```
BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal("12.1212123456543234");
```

If you want to round the decimal up to N digits, you can do it this way:

```
BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal("12.1212123456543234");
decimal = decimal.setScale(15, RoundingMode.CEILING);
```

You should also have a look at [RoundingModes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) to select the rounding you need.